# Removing \n from readlines with rstrip("\n")

Tags: python, python-2.7

im reading 2 files per lines that contains strings 
and grouping per other one here in my code im grooping 1 line from proxyfile with 3 lines from websitefiles
major problem when i try to print the lines from 2nd file i cant remove the \n

i have tried to use rstrip("\n") but i got this exception

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

this is my code :

```
proxy = open("proxy.txt",'r')
readproxy = proxy.readlines()

sites = open("websites.txt",'r')
readsites = sites.readlines()

for i,j in zip(readproxy, zip(*(iter(readsites),) * 3)):

    try:
        i = i.rstrip("\n")
        #j = j.rstrip("\n")
        print(i,j)
    except ValueError:
        print 'whatever'
```

i removed the \n from "i" successfully , but coudent remove it from "j"

this screenshot can explain all i think
[image: screen1]

Comment: Yes, the screenshot explains everything: `j` is a tuple, and it's not possible to call `rstrip` on tuples since they don't have this method.

Comment: Please change the screenshot into a copy-paste of the actual output; that is much more readable.

Comment: If you want to strip the newline from every element inside the tuple, you'll need to iterate over `j`, strip each item, and collect all items again into a tuple or list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tuple` doesn't have a method that magically propagates to all string elements.

To do that you have to apply `rstrip` for all items in a list comprehension to create a `list`.

```
j = [x.rstrip("\n") for x in j]
```

that rebuilds a `list` with items stripped. Convert to `tuple` if really needed:

```
j = tuple(x.rstrip("\n") for x in j)
```

note that you could avoid this post processing by doing:

```
readsites = sites.read().splitlines()
```

instead of `sites.readlines()` since `splitlines` splits into lines while removing the termination character if no argument is specified. The only drawback is in the case when the file is huge. In that case, you could encounter a memory issue (memory needed by read + split is doubled). In which case, you could do:

```
with open("websites.txt",'r') as sites:
    readsites = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in sites]
```

Comment: clean and perfect .